# NSString or NSMutableString category for templating

Tags: iphone, templates, nsstring, nsmutablestring

Is anyone aware of a category on NSString or NSMutableString that allows for templating?  I'd like to create a template and use tags for variables, then "apply" a KVC-compliant object against the string to have the variables replaced.

Or another way of asking... How is templating currently done in the iPhone / Objective-C universe?  Is there a class out there that already handles this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MGTemplateEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/05/20/mgtemplateengine-templates-with-cocoa) works on Mac OS X and on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [MGTemplateEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/05/20/mgtemplateengine-templates-with-cocoa). The comments on the linked article suggest iPhone compatibility is now available.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/groue/GRMustache is an Objective-C implementation of the Mustache template language.